# How to create an object of Foreign class key in python with filter?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I came across the problem of creating an object which doesn't exist. The models are as follows:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

class Phone(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact,related_name='contact_number')
    number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Now, when I fire a query

```
Contact.objects.filter(id=1031).values('contact_number')

The Output is:
<QuerySet [{'contact_number': None}]>
```

Can there be any Query for creating the contact_number for the same when it is None? Because if I update

```
Contact.objects.filter(id = 1031).update(contact_number = '9999999999') it gives me an error? 
Error: AttributeError: 'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'get_db_prep_save'
```

What can be the possible correct query for creating it?

Comment: so, you want to create a `phone` object and the `contact` will be the foreign key to this id `1031`, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
Phone.objects.create(contact_id=1031, number='99999999')
```